# Accessing ignored HTML tags in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, xhtml-1.0-strict

If we have a form tag without action attribute `<form id='SomeForm'>..</form>` in **strict DOCTYPE**, the renderer would **ignore the form tag** and F12 dev tools for IE and Firebug for FF will not show that form element in the rendered DOM. But the raw HTML (view source) will show it.

I tried to access the form via jQuery, but `$('#SomeFrom')` returns an empty array `[]`.

If I change the DOCTYPE to transitional, it works. But my application-wide setting requires strict DOCTYPE. Is there a way to access the raw (source) HTML of the page via JavaScript?

**Notes:**

I am using SharePoint 2010 CMS. When I edit the HTML of the page and save it, it truncates the action part. Basically, its not the recommended way of creating form in it but I have already created lot of pages with forms. Now I need some scripting to validate, stringify and ajaxify them with same handler.

Also using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186309) approach I can wrap the form-fields in a div and stringify and submit them like this:

`JSON.stringify($("div#SomeForm input, div#SomeForm textarea, div#SomeForm select").serializeObject())`

But if I would be able to access the form, the code will be more niftier and the same I could use jQuery's validate extension as well.

Comment: Why can't you add the action attribute? If you are submitting to the same page, you can leave it blank or hard-code the same location

Comment: Have you tried document.getElementById('SomeForm'); ?

Comment: @LinusPersson, yes I did and its empty.

Comment: Ok then I suggest you try what @hsalama said =)

Comment: _dev tools ... will not show that form element in the rendered DOM_ -- Kind of answered your own question, right?

Comment: View Source gives you the html prior to the browser interacting with it. Once the browser parses it, those elements are gone. You won't be able to select those elements because the browser is unaware of them at that point. The only solution would be to make the element valid so that the browser doesn't remove it.

Comment: @hsalama, check the updated **Notes**.